# Shrinking of objects in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, time-dilation

As well describe by special relativity,  an object moving at high speed will look shrunk by an observer outside the reference frame at rest.

My question is, in the context of general-relativity, should we not observe  that object appears smaller, close to an intense gravitational field (if we measure it outside of the gravitational field)? Something similar to a Lorentz transformation, but for an accelerating reference frame?

Thank in advanced.

Comment: My intuition tells me there will be such an effect but it won’t be as acute as Lorentz contraction. Instead a more general distortion in the direction of curvature is likely, similar to gravitational lensing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gravitational Length Contraction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/130182/gravitational-length-contraction). In short, length contraction isn't a thing in GR because we can only make those measurements locally. Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/145264/length-contraction-in-a-gravitational-field?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Eletie Yes it does , thank to you !